# Will compiler generate different .pdb file for the same sources

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, pdb-files

I know that I should avoid it as long as possible but let's talk about urgent cases.

What's the chances that .pdb file generated from the same source code with the same libraries produces different result on every build?

Yes, I know that it will differ in GUID but I can change it manually.

Suppose that I don't have a corresponding .pdb file but I know which source code was used to compile the specified product's version.

Comment: I suspect you're asking this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744870/how-can-you-change-an-age-mismatched-pdb-to-match-properly)

Comment: @UKMonkey I'm not asking about how to change the GUID. Please reread my question

Comment: Are you asking if the compiler output is deterministic?

Comment: @Raw N Yeah, something like that. I know that it generally doesn't but I don't have any other option at the moment

Answer (score 0):

What I know that you could find the mismatched information for different pdb files with the same source code like this blog except the GUID:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2007/11/05/mismatched-pdbs-why/

A thread also shared some information about the timestamp which should be match here:

[Compiler PDB file and the Linker PDB file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796090/compiler-pdb-file-and-the-linker-pdb-file)

Comment: I know. Please reread the question -- "Yes, I know that it will differ in GUID but I can change it manually"

Comment: @FrozenHeart, So the real issue is that you want to know that whether there are other differences except the GUID for PDB files, am I right?